# Compacting garbage collector implementation in C++0x

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, c++11

I'm implementing a compacting garbage collector for my own personal use in C++0x, and I've got a question. Obviously the mechanics of the collector depend upon moving objects, and I've been wondering how to implement this in terms of the smart pointer types that point to it. I've been thinking about either pointer-to-pointer in the pointer type itself, or, the collector maintains a list of pointers that point to each object so that they can be modified, removing the need for a double de-ref when accessing the pointer but adding some extra overhead during collection and additional memory overhead. What's the best way to go here?

Edit: My primary concern is for speedy allocation and access. I'm not concerned with particularly efficient collections or other maintenance, because that's not really what the GC is intended for.

Comment: Have fun with that headache, especially with making sure everything goes through that layer of indirection that's required - in the meanwhile, I will write my code (as much as possible) in languages that already have a garbage collector. +1 out of sympathy (no, it's really an interesting question).

Comment: @delnan: They have to solve this problem just as much as I do, it's just behind the scenes.

Comment: Languages with compacting GC have to, yes - but we don't have to ;)

Comment: "Best"?  We need your requirements.  Is the runtime and space overhead acceptable?  (Should we guess for you?)  Hopefully you're not trying to micro-optimize performance at this stage.

Comment: @Fred: The aim is to minimize the cost of allocation and access, not maintenance.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of doing search and replace during compaction? This avoids the indirection and increased storage, but you pay for the linear search. I guess it'd depend on frequency of access versus frequency of GC runs - remember that a smaller working set often increases speed (by reducing cache misses).

Comment: @phlip: I don't quite understand. Search and replace where? I can't just go looking down the stack or in the heap for `gc_pointer<T>`.

Comment: Why not just use Hans Boehm's existing C++ GC? http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/

Comment: @dajames: Because it's supplementing `new`, not replacing it.

Comment: Are you planning on making your compacting GC implementation open source?

Comment: @Daniel: It's pretty unlikely. I'm fairly certain that I've produced an alternative anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: I hadn't thought about that: sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straight-forward question so here's a straight-forward answer:

`Mark-and-sweep` (and occasionally `mark-and-compact` to avoid heap fragmentation) is the fastest when it comes to allocation and access (avoiding double de-refs). It's also very easy to implement. Since you're not worried about collection performance impact (mark-and-sweep tends to freeze up the process in a nondeterministically), this should be the way to go.

Implementation details found at:

- http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html#secgarbagemarksweep
- http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page428.html

Comment: That seems easy- if the only GC references exist on the stack, native heap, or static allocation. How would I handle GC references from the native heap?

Comment: I mean, stack, GC heap, or static alloc.

Comment: -1 Actually mark-sweep has relatively poor allocation performance. Generational provides fast allocation and is usually combined with mark-sweep for the oldest generation.

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing straight forward about grafting on extra GC to C++, let alone a compacting algorithm. It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do and how it will interact with the rest of the C++ code.

I have actually written a gc in C++ which works with existing C++ code, and it had a compactor at one stage (though I dropped it because it was too slow). But there are many nasty semantic problems. I mentioned to Bjarne only a few weeks ago that C++ lacks the operator required to do it properly and the situation is that it is unlikely to ever exist because it has limited utility..

What you actually need is a "re-addres-me" operator. What happens is that you do not actually move objects around. You just use mmap to change the object address. This is much faster, and, in effect, it is using the VM features to provide handles.

Without this facility you have to have a way to perform an *overlapping* move of an object, which you cannot do in C++ efficiently: you'd have to move to a temporary first. In C, it is much easier, you can use `memmove`. At some stage all the pointers to or into the moved objects have to be adjusted.

Using handles does *not* solve this problem, it just reduces the problem from arbitrary sized objects to constant sized ones: these are easier to manage in an array, but the same problem exists: you have to manage the storage. If you remove lots of handle from the array randomly .. you still have a problem with fragmentation.

So don't bother with handles, they don't work.

This is what I did in Felix: you call `new(shape, collector) T(args)`. Here the `shape` is a descriptor of the type, including a list of offsets which contain (GC) pointers, and the address of a routine to finalise the object (by default, it calls the destructor).

It also contains a flag saying if the object can be moved with `memmove`. If the object is big or immobile, it is allocated by `malloc`. If the object is small and mobile, it is allocated in an arena, provided there is space in the arena.

The arena is compacted by moving all the objects in it, and using the shape information to globally adjust all the pointers to or into these objects. Compaction can be done incrementally.

The downside for a C++ programmer is the need to construct a correct `shape` object to pass. This doesn't bother me because I'm implementing a language which can generate the shape information automatically.

Now: the key point is: to do compaction, you **must** use a precise collector. Compaction cannot work with a conservative collector. This is very important. It is fine to allow some leakage if you see an value that looks like a pointer but happens to be an integer: some object won't be collected, but this is usually no big deal. But for compaction you have to *adjust* the pointers but you'd better not change that integer: so you have to know *for sure* when something is a pointer, so your collector has to be precise: the shape must be known.

In Ocaml this is relatively simple: everything is either a pointer or integer and the low bit is used at run time to tell. Objects pointed at have a code telling the type, and there are only a few types: either a scalar (don't scan it) or an aggregate (scan it, it only contains integers or pointers).

Comment: With handles, I can see why the size of the handle pool will be the maximum number of handles that have ever existed, but if handles are not sharable (code wanting a copy of a reference stored in a handle must construct a new handle, copy the reference from the old one to the new one, and then destruct its new handle when no longer needed) I would think they could be quickly and easily recycled.  Unless a task needs a huge number of handles and then never again needs anything near that many, I don't see why fragmentation would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A nursery generation will give you the best possible allocation performance because it is just a pointer bump.

You could implement pointer updates without using double indirection by using techniques like a shadow stack but this will be slow and very error prone if you're writing this C++ code by hand.

Comment: Actually if you're wrapping C++ code, the best performance is obtained by avoiding GC. In general, global GC is a very bad. It doesn't scale, it wipes out your cache, won't play with multi-processing, etc.  [Look at Ocaml, still stuck in single thread land] GC won't become viable until you can partition and localise the operations, and avoid the GC when not required. Boxing in FPLs is evil here. Rust language is designed to achieve many of these goals, however it drops multi-threading (shared memory concurrency) to achieve this.

Comment: Just so its clear: Felix uses a really slow naive collector which dare not move things (the compactor got dropped). However that doesn't mean it is slow, because it can also do things like a traditional C++ list object, which doesn't require any GC: it uses abstraction to isolate the object nodes from the outside world. GC needs to scan for pointers in list values but never has to reap nodes. So using C++ we have eliminated the need for GC in one part of the program. GC is really only need when there are cycles.